# Number Partitions

Tags: integer-partitions

Is this series complete, using '0' is not allowed:

$6 = 6$ or $5+1$ or $1+5$ or $4+2$ or $2+4$ or $3+3$ or $4+1+1$ or $1+4+1$ or $1+1+4$ or $1+2+3$ or $1+3+2$ or $2+3+1$ or $2+1+3$ or $3+1+2$ or $3+2+1$ or $1+1+1+3$ or $1+1+3+1$ or $1+3+1+1$ or $3+1+1+1$ or $1+1+1+1+2$ or $1+1+1+2+1$ or $1+1+2+1+1$ or $1+2+1+1+1$ or $2+1+1+1+1$ or $1+1+1+1+1+1$

5 = 5 or 4+1 or 1+4 or 3+2 or 2+3 or 1+1+3 or 3+1+1 or 1+3+1 or 1+2+2 or     2+1+2 or 2+2+1 or 2+1+1+1 or 1+2+1+1 or 1+1+2+1 or 1+1+1+2 or 1+1+1+1+1

4 = 4 or 3+1 or 2+2 or 1+3 or 1+1+2 or 1+2+1 or 2+1+1 or 1+1+1+1

3 = 3 or 1+1+1 or 1+2 or 2+1

2 = 2 or 1+1

1 = 1

The number of partitions in this series is 1,2,4,8,16,25.

Have I missed any, as 25 seems odd to me.

Comment: 2+2+2 has been missed. There are 6 others. In total, there are 32.

Answer (score 3):

You have missed seven ways. Mainly, $$2+2+2=6$$$$1+1+2+2=6$$$$1+2+1+2=6$$$$1+2+2+1=6$$$$2+1+2+1=6$$$$2+2+1+1=6$$$$2+1+1+2=6$$So there are $32$ ways. However, one thing worth mentioning is that your definition strays from the normal definition of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)), where two sums that differ only in the order of their summands are considered the same partition. In fact, if the order matters, as in your case, the correct term is a [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)).